# Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, brain.js

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([
  {
    input: [0, 0]
    output: [0]
  },
  {
    input: [1, 0]
    output: [1]
  },
  {
    input: [0, 1]
    output: [1]
  },
  {
    input: [1, 1]
    output: [0]
  }
])


const diagram = document.getElementById('diagram')
diagram.innerHTML = brain.utilities.toSVG(net)
```

This should show me the neural network diagram but it doesn't I do have the HTML all set up and it's supposed to be working correctly but when I run it first it loads for longer than usual code does but I suppose its because I'm working with more complex stuff than usual and well I just get a blank screen so I would like if someone would help me out by telling me what the problem is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Storm</title>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js" defer></script>
    <script src="index.js" defer> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="diagram">Diagram </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you just copying and pasting a tutorial and trying to run it in the browser? How are you running this?

Comment: @GentryTran yes is something wrong?

Comment: is there a special software I'm supposed to run it in @GentryTran

Comment: You can let me know if the answer below is your issue. You can mark it if it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import is this:

```
    <script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js" defer></script>
```

But needs to be this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/brain.js@1.0.0-rc.3/browser.js"></script>
```

`https://` implies it will download it from a website, whereas yours
`//` implies it will look on your local machine (your computer) for the file.

Since you didn't download the file, it won't load anything.

Maybe you want to use a different package, but the main issue is the import.

Comment: I did that thanks for showing me it but I still have a black screen is brain.js supposed to run in some software and not in a browser?

Comment: Try this one: https://scrimba.com/scrim/c36zkcb

Comment: If you copy only the html and the .js file to https://codepen.io/pen/, it will work with solely those two files, like what you have above.

Comment: that seems usefull thanks

Comment: Usually, you would run something like this using node, which is basically the javascript engine taken out of chrome to run on a desktop without running the browser. Node can download all of the files you need to run, and then you could get your program running from there. There are many tutorials of how to use it and set it up. I'd recommend looking at some youtube tutorials of setting up basic javascript projects first, then try this. Mosh has good tutorials on node.